# store multiple integer values in one list and return best value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following three integer values:

```
id        # identifies the pair
entropy   # gives entropy information
len       # basicly the length of a string
```

now i want to store many of these values and select the top 10 having the highest entropy overall and a length value over `n`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for id, entropy, len in generateValues:
    d[id].append(entropy)
    d[id].append(len)

# now get the top 10 values
```

Can this be easily done?

Comment: Why do you use a defaultdict? Can't you just set this up with `d[id] = [entropy, len]`

Comment: @jamylak the first thing that google told me was the defaultdict... i will consider your solution as more readable :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the top 10 values after you've constructed the dictionary like this. Although there would be a more efficient solution if you find them as you construct the dictionary if that's possible.

```
import heapq
heapq.nlargest(10, (k for k in d if d[k][1] > n), key=lambda k: d[k][0])
```

Comment: cool didn't know about heapq, is it just me or is the algorithm similar to mptts

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, `sorted` supports a `key` argument:

```
filtered = ((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if v[1] > n) # or filter(d.iteritems(), lambda t: t[1][1] > n)
topTen = sorted(filtered, key=lambda t: t[0], reversed=true)[:10]
```

This is, imho, more readable than (and of equivalent efficiency to) the solutions using heapq.

Comment: Well this is O(n log n), the heapq is O(n). Probably doesn't matter until there is a _lot_ of values though

Comment: @gnibbler Isn't heapifying data O(n log n)? Or am I either misremembering, or mistaking how `nlargest` works?

Comment: @RoadieRich the data is not heapified (but heapifying takes O(N) linear time anyway), it's just a function inside `heapq` module which may be misleading